# What is the best practice of sharing an OneToMany to others?

Tags: jpa, entity-relationship

Let's say I have a table looks like this.

```
K VARCHAR PK
V VARCHAR
```

It's just a single table stores entries of keys and values.

Now, I want it be used for other entities commonly.

Entity A have multiple properties and Entity B could have multiple properties.

```
@Entity
class Property {

    String key;
    String value;
}
```

What is the best practice for sharing the `Property` entity to other entities?

```
@Entity
class Some {

    @OneToMany
    private List<...Property> properties;
}

@Entity
class SomeOther {

    @OneToMany
    private List<...Property> properties;
}
```

I planning to use inheritance.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
class Property {
}
```

And I know I can extend it.

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SomeOther")
class SomeProperty extends Property {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SomeOther")
class SomeOtherProperty extends Property {
}
```

Now How can should my tables look like?

Should I create `SOME_PROPERTY` table?

Or should I add `SOME_ID` into `PROPERTY` table?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd try keeping things simple.

The current mapping, i.e.:

```
@Entity
class Some {

    @OneToMany
    private List<Property> properties;
}
```

creates a join table that links rows in `SOME` and `PROPERTY`. You'll get almost the same with `InheritanceType.JOINED`.

If you modify your mapping slightly:

```
@Entity
class Some {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn
    private List<Property> properties;
}
```

you'll end up with a foreign key in `PROPERTY` pointing to `SOME` (and reusing this mapping for `SomeOther` will result in yet another foreign key). You'll get almost the same with `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE`.

Using inheritance here will only complicate things. I'd go with one of the options above, or use an even simpler mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Some {

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "K")
    @Column(name = "V")
    @CollectionTable(name = "PROPERTY", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "some_id"))
    private Map<String, String> properties;
}
```

The above represents the properties as a `Map<String, String>`, which is really what they are. The only downside is that when you reuse this mapping (changing only the join column name, e.g. `some_other_id`), your JPA provider might have difficulty generating the schema. You can, of course, decide to keep the properties for different entities separate, in which case you could change the collection table name (you would then get the equivalent of `Inheritance.TABLE_PER_CLASS`).

BTW I don't think it makes sense for `K` to be the primary key, assuming keys will be repeated for different instances of `Some`. If you decide on one of the solutions using `@OneToMany`, I'd recommend adding a surrogate key (an `@Id @GeneratedValue Long id` field) to the `Property` entity.